# use column in angularjs uigrid

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using angularjs uigrid with $scope http to get data from controller.
now here i used columns like this:

```html
<div ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller="HelloController">
      <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
var StudentApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.grid']);

StudentApp.controller('HelloController', function ($scope, StudentService) {
    $scope.columnDefs = [
 { field: 'FirstName', title: 'fname'  },
 { field: 'Last Name' },
 { field: 'Salary' },
 { field: 'DOB' }
 ],
        getStudents();
    function getStudents() {
        StudentService.getStudents()
            .success(function (studs) {
                $scope.myData = studs;
                console.log($scope.students);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    }
});

StudentApp.factory('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var StudentService = {};
    StudentService.getStudents = function () {

        return $http.get('/Home/GetEmployee');
    };
    return StudentService;

} ]);
</script>
```

in this i have used $scope.columndefs but it is not working.
And how to format date value here?
When i run this apps value is showing in below like after some 30 lines value is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller="HelloController">
     <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridoptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var StudentApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.grid']);

StudentApp.controller('HelloController', function ($scope, StudentService) {
    $scope.columnDefs = [
 { field: 'FirstName', title: 'fname'  },
 { field: 'Last Name' },
 { field: 'Salary' },
 { field: 'DOB' }
 ],


  $scope.gridoptions = {
   data:'myData',
   columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs,
  }

            getStudents();
        function getStudents() {
            StudentService.getStudents()
                .success(function (studs) {
                    $scope.myData = studs;
                    console.log($scope.students);
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
                    console.log($scope.status);
                });
        }
    });

    StudentApp.factory('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var StudentService = {};
        StudentService.getStudents = function () {

            return $http.get('/Home/GetEmployee');
        };
        return StudentService;

    } ]);
    </script>
```

I hope this would work.